# display duplicate record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called problemTBL, which contains the fields below

```
problem_id Autoincrement,Pk
passenger_id, accept duplicate values
problem_name, problem description
```

These are sample records:

```
Problem_id passenger_id    problem_name
1              22         NO Air condition 
2              22         Dirty Seats
3              24         Driver Not helped
4              22         Old Age Car
5              23         Old Age Driver
6              22         Very speed driving
```

Now I want to retrieve a record like

```
["NO Air condition","Dirty Seats","Old Age Car","Very speed driving","","","","","","","","","","",""] passenger_id 22

["Driver Not helped","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""] passenger_id 24
```

OR

```
passenger_id    problem_name
22              NO Air condition |=| Dirty Seats |=| Very speed driving |=|Old Age Car
24              Driver Not helped
23              Old Age Driver
```

Is it possible with a query?

Hi the thing , am doing migration ,

at present i kept all the problem in each now, now i am doing migration ,
i want to keep all problem for the particular customer into one single row,

That is one customer can raise compliant upto 15 only(For complaint we have seprate form , there we asking some questions, they just tick and submit..)

So we have decided clearly that is only 15 problem ,

So one row for one customer,

That is now latest compliant form have 15 complaint , if they selected , then that problem will check else empty val will be insert ,

While submiting the form am just post all values into json_encoded and then am insert this json into table...

Got it my point...

For future complaint i done program well,

But past compliants i want to migrate , so that i posted question here,.,,

Comment: Why do you have all these: `"","","","","","","","","","","","","",""` ?

Comment: @NullUserException looks like the OP is returning a set of 15 problems

Comment: I feel you would be better revising your table layout... than to write this query.

Comment: Why is "old age driver" a problem? Isn't that politically incorrect?

Comment: Hi NullUserException  we are just maintaining like that

Comment: (edit)The table structure is fine.(/)  I think you might be asking about pivot tables. My first question is, why don't you just return with an order by passenger ID, it would be just as easy to work with in code and a lot easier and faster to generate from the DB...

Answer (score 1):

You may use group_concat() to aggregate text fields from multiple rows.

```
SELECT
        `passenger_id`, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(`problem_name` SEPARATOR ' |=| ')
FROM
    `problemTBL`
GROUP BY 
    `passenger_id`
```

Additionally you may wish to increase group_concat_max_len variable.

Before SELECT query:
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = max_bytes

Answer (score 0):

read about cross-tabulations (aka pivot tables) here:

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2003/12/04/crosstabs.html